# Replacing values of pandas data frame to lists using dictionary mapping?

Tags: python, pandas

If we have a pandas data frame and a mapping dictionary for the values in the data frame, replacing the values in the data frame using the dictionary as a mapping can be done like so:

```
In: df
Out:
  Col1 Col2
0    a    c
1    b    c
2    b    c

In: key
Out: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

In: df.replace(key)
Out: 
   Col1  Col2
0     1     3
1     2     3
2     2     3
```

How can a similar transformation be accomplished when the mapping dictionary has lists as values?  For example:

```
In: key
Out: {'a': [1, 0, 0], 'b': [0, 1, 0], 'c': [0, 0, 1]}

In: df.replace(key)
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 1 output values where the mask is true
```

In this example, the end goal would be to have a new data frame that has 3 rows and 6 columns:

```
1 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can `applymap`+`explode`+reshape:

```
df2 = df.applymap(key.get).explode(list(df.columns))
df2 = (df2
 .set_index(df2.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
 .unstack(level=1)
)
```

output:

```
  Col1       Col2      
     0  1  2    0  1  2
0    1  0  0    0  0  1
1    0  1  0    0  0  1
2    0  1  0    0  0  1
```

*NB. to reset the columns: `df2.columns = range(df2.shape[1])`*

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  0  0  0  1
1  0  1  0  0  0  1
2  0  1  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: `df.applymap(key.get)` - cool!

Comment: @richardec not efficient though (like a loop), but better that `literal_eval` I guess :p I haven't had time to look your answer yet

Comment: I came up with [something else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71501145/17242583): converting `key` to a Series and indexing _it_ with `key` ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination `DataFrame.apply` and `Series.map` to perform this substitution. From there, you can perform a `DataFrame.sum` to concatenate the lists and then cast your data back into a new `DataFrame`

```py
out = pd.DataFrame(
    df.apply(lambda s: s.map(key)).sum(axis=1).tolist()
)

print(out)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  0  0  0  1
1  0  1  0  0  0  1
2  0  1  0  0  0  1
```

---

Semi-related testing of `.sum` vs `.chain`:

```
In [22]: %timeit tmp_df.sum(axis=1)
77.6 µs ± 1.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [23]: %timeit tmp_df.apply(lambda row: list(chain.from_iterable(row)), axis=1)
197 µs ± 1.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [24]: tmp_df
Out[24]: 
        Col1       Col2
0  [1, 0, 0]  [0, 0, 1]
1  [0, 1, 0]  [0, 0, 1]
2  [0, 1, 0]  [0, 0, 1]
```

While I won't say that `.sum` is the best method for concatenating lists in a Series, `.apply` & `chain.from_iterable` doesn't seem to fair much better- **at least on a very small sample like this.**

Comment: Beware of `sum` on Series of lists. This looks fancy but the efficiency is quite bad. It's more efficient to apply a `chain` ;)

Comment: Curious if my implementation differs from what you had in mind?

Comment: you need to test on more columns. Try 2k columns, I got ~90 ms for `sum` vs ~2-3 ms for `chain`. The inefficiency of `sum` comes from the fact that it generates a new list at each step ;)

Comment: For 20k rows the `sum` is not even computing vs 20 ms for `chain`.

Comment: Love it, thanks for the explanation and clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, this is tricky.

One solution I came up with is to convert the lists to their string represention before replacing with them, because pandas treats `list`s specially. Then you can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` on each row to combine all the lists into one big list, and create a dataframe out of that:

```
import ast
from itertools import chain

n = df.replace({k: str(v) for k, v in key.items()}).applymap(ast.literal_eval)
df  =pd.DataFrame(n.apply(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x)), axis=1).tolist())
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  0  0  0  1
1  0  1  0  0  0  1
2  0  1  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method of replacing the items with lists without looping or stringifying:

```
df[:] = pd.Series(key)[df.to_numpy().flatten()].to_numpy().reshape(df.shape)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Col1       Col2
0  [1, 0, 0]  [0, 0, 1]
1  [0, 1, 0]  [0, 0, 1]
2  [0, 1, 0]  [0, 0, 1]
```

Or, you can use `explode` and `reshape` to convert the data directly to a numpy array:

```
arr = pd.Series(key)[df.to_numpy().flatten()].explode().to_numpy().reshape(-1, 6) # 6 = len of one of the items of `key` * number of columns in df
```

Output:

```
>>> arr
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=object)
       
>>> pd.DataFrame(arr)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  0  0  0  1
1  0  1  0  0  0  1
2  0  1  0  0  0  1
```